# Adding class selector after pseudo selector in css

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors, pseudo-class

Can I add a class selector after a pseudo class in my CSS rule, e.g:

```
a:hover.my-class {
    background: red;
}
```

So if I hover over my anchor tag, `<a class="my-class">link</a>`, will the background be red in all browsers? is this valid CSS?

---

**Why I need this**

I have this problem because it is generated from a mixin in SASS:

```
@mixin focus($classA, $classB) {
  &:focus {
    &#{$classA} {
      background: blue;
    }

    &#{$classB} {
      background: yellow;
    }
  }
}

a {
  @include focus('.class-a', '.class-b')
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "pseudo-selector".

There are two features in selectors that start with "pseudo-": pseudo-class and pseudo-element. They are completely different features with different syntax rules.

You *can* place a class selector after a pseudo-class such as `:hover`, because they are both simple selectors and order of simple selectors in a compound selector does not matter (type and universal selectors are the only exceptions to this rule — they always have to come first, such as the `a` in your example).

You *cannot* place a class selector after a pseudo-element such as `::before`, because a pseudo-element is not a simple selector. Your question may not be about pseudo-elements, but this distinction has to be made because of the common use of the term "pseudo-selector", which incorrectly groups both features into a single umbrella term (and frankly makes the question more complicated than it *really* needs to be).

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you can add a class to a pseudo class.

This css is valid and it works:

```
a:hover.hoverme {
  background:blue;
  color:white;
}
```

This works too:

```
a.hoverme:hover {
  background:blue;
  color:white;
}
```

Or you can add a pseudo class after a class.

```css
.hoverme:hover {
  background:blue;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="hoverme">Hover me!</a>
```

You can check if your CSS is valid at W3C's [CSS Validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator) page.